# Unable to visual python (vpython) in Enthought Canopy on Windows 7

Tags: python, enthought, canopy, vpython

I installed Enthought Canopy (free version) on Windows 7.

I wanted to install visual python (vpython).

I tried everything, pip install vpython, isn't available.

Tried to download the latest zip, from here: https://codeload.github.com/BruceSherwood/vpython-wx/zip/master and then I introduced in the Canopy console: pip install/directory/vpython-wx-src.6.05b.zip (the correct directory and filename).

Doesn't install and this appear:

```
Unpacking c:\users\teo\downloads\vpython-wx-src.6.05b.zip
Running setup.py egg_info for package from file:///c%7C%5Cusers%5Cteo%5Cdownloads%5Cvpython-wx-src.6.05b.zip
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.34.tar.gz
Extracting in c:\users\teo\appdata\local\temp\tmprfdxhf
Now working in c:\users\teo\appdata\local\temp\tmprfdxhf\distribute-0.6.34
Building a Distribute egg in c:\users\teo\appdata\local\temp\pip-e84ef9-build
c:\users\teo\appdata\local\temp\pip-e84ef9-build\distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg

warning: no files found matching 'site-packages\visual\docs\navigation.js'
Downloading/unpacking fontTools (from VPython==6.05)
Downloading FontTools-2.4.tar.gz (323Kb): 323Kb downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package fontTools
C:\Users\Teo\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86_64\lib\distutils\dist.py:267:
UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'console'
warnings.warn(msg)
WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py

warning: no files found matching 'Doc\ChangeLog'
Downloading/unpacking Polygon (from VPython==6.05)
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Polygon (from VPython==6.05)
No distributions at all found for Polygon (from VPython==6.05)
Storing complete log in C:\Users\Teo\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.log
```

Can someone help me? In Enthought support it says: "If you have questions that are not answered there, please post them to Stack Overflow with tag "enthought"", but I'm not able to tag it.

**Edit:** As the log file was to big to post it here, it is here:

http://www51.zippyshare.com/v/47998264/file.html

Comment: What's in complete log in `C:\Users\Teo\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.log` ?

Comment: `I installed Enthought Canopy (free version) on Windows 7, because this is the only way that i can put python working.` Can you expand a bit about this? My feeling is that python is one of the user-friendliest platform out there.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Python works fine, the problem are modules, can't install them, installers can't find python (strange, but never tested with pip, just the installers, so decided to use Canopy). I will post the logs right now. Thanks for help

Comment: Can't post log file, i will make upload and put a link (it is bigger than the limit of stockexchange) - http://www51.zippyshare.com/v/47998264/file.html

Comment: Do you specifically have to use Enthought? Based on the original version of your question, it sounds as though you cannot use the regular python.org Python due to installation issues (most likely related to not having administrator privileges), and that is the only reason you tried Enthought. If that is the case, you have other choices. In particular, [WinPython](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/) can be run in a portable manner, and it already comes bundled with VPython.

Comment: No, i have administrator privileges. Ok, i will try winpython, thx

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to install vpython in Enthought Canopy is to

1. Be sure that you have made Canopy be your default Python (Preferences Menu).
2. Download and install Chris Gohlke's VPython installer for Windows: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#vpython